# Can't add class to Django form fields

Tags: django

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Using the code above, only the username has the form-control class, and the email doesn't. Why is that?

I found a work around that makes the email field has form-control class, which is

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

However, I really don't want it to look like this. Is there a way to make it work like the 1st piece of code?

the template file is just simple

```
<div class="form-group">
     <form id="register" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}                       
          {{ form.as_p }}
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `email = forms.EmailField()` where you already have `email` in fields in 1st piece ? try to remove this and test

Comment: @PankajSharma email isn't a default field of UserCreationForm